# Deploying C application using Puppet

Tags: c, puppet

our organization is using puppet to deploy applications. Most of the literature is focused on newer technologies, we have some outliers like C that needs deployment using Puppet.

Can anyone point me to a good tutorial or example?

Comment: can you please show your effort?

Comment: What is exactly the difference with "newer technologies" ?